# VMware ESXi 4.1: unable to change host name

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I'm running the free ESXi 4.1 on a server and use the free vSphere Client to access the server.  I would like to change the host name from `localhost.$DOMAIN` to something else, but when I go to Configuration -> DNS and Routing -> Properties, the Name and Domain boxes are grayed out and I can't edit them.  What do I have to do to change the host name?

Comment: Are you logged into the ESXi server with an account that has rights to change the hostname?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it via the console on the host.

Hit F2, enter user/password, 'Configure Management Network', 'DNS Configuration', 'Hostname' - then save and restart the management network.

Then just remove/re-add the host into your VC/cluster.

Comment: Changing the DNS settings from automatic to manual also enables me to change the host name.

Comment: great news, glad you're sorted

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are logged in with an account with administrative privileges (e.g. root), the reason it's greyed out is because it is configured to use DHCP. The hostname is set to localhost when this is the case. Switch out of DHCP made and you should be able to change the hostname to something else; either via the console or GUI.